# WPF DataGridTextColumn FontWeight Binding / Value Converter not working

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I understand the concept of Binding / Value converter well, but for some reasons the following binding doesn't work. I would like the change the `FontWeight` to `Bold` for some Descriptions (`Description` is a text field):

XAML:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Description"
                    Binding="{Binding Description}"
                    FontWeight="{Binding Description, Converter={converters:DescriptionToFontWeightConverter}}"/>
```

Value converter method (simplified):

```
public class DescriptionToFontWeightConverter : ConverterMarkupExtension<DescriptionToFontWeightConverter>
{
    public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Some logic based on the value
        // ..
        
        return "Bold"; // I believe I should use "Bold", and not "FontWeights.Bold" here (like it would be with a dependency property, but the problem is that it doesn't go inside the method.
    }

    public override object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) => Binding.DoNothing;
}
```

I believe the problem comes from the binding path of the FontWeight property. For example, if I replace `(Path=)Description` by `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}`, it goes inside the value converter method, but I don't think I can retrieve the value of the binding.. I think it isn't something abnormal (at least something I didn't expect), but I wonder if I shouldn't replace the `DataGridTextColum` by a `DataGridTemplateColum` and digs further?

I use the ConvertMarkupExtension method from [this website](https://www.broculos.net/2014/04/wpf-how-to-use-converters-without.html) which doesn't require to specify the value converters as static resources.

**UPDATE with `DataGridColumnTemplate`**

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Description">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight"
                                Value="{Binding Description, Converter={converters:DescriptionToFontWeightConverter}}"/>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Description}"/>
        </DataTemplate>                    
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Thanks for any insights :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DataGridColumn` doesn't inherit any `DataContext` so trying to bind to a `Description` property of the current item will always fail.

The `Binding` property is special. Its type is `Binding` and the binding that you define in XAML will eventually be applied to the element that gets created at runtime. In the case of a `DataGridTextColumn`, this is a `TextBlock` or a `TextBox` depending on whether you are in edit mode.

> but I wonder if I shouldn't replace the DataGridTextColum by a DataGridTemplateColum and digs further

If you use a `DataGridTemplateColumn` and define a `TextBlock` in the `CellTemplate` (and a `TextBox` in the `CellEditingTemplate`), you can actually bind to a property of the current item as usual. This is because the element in the template is added to the element tree and inherits a `DataContext` like any other *element*.

Comment: OK, thanks. I made the modification (see update) and it perfectly works, but I'm not so sure if I will actually allow direct editing. I don't really know why, but something prevented me to "just" try..

Comment: @Or8e4m4n: The `CellEditingTemplate` with the `TextBlock` will be shown you are in edit mode so this should work.